# Compare two Pandas Series/DataFrames that are virtually equal

Tags: python, unit-testing, pandas

For a unittest I have to compare two pandas DataFrames (with one column, so they can also be cast to Series without losing information). The problem is that the index of one is of datetime type, the other date. For our purposes the information in the two is equal, since the time component of the datetime is not used.

To check if the two objects are equal for a unittest I could:

- Extract the index of one of them and cast to date/datetime
- Extract just the values of the one column, compare those and start and end dates

Am I missing any elegant way to compare the two?

Code example:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

days_in_training = 40
start_date = date(2016, 12, 1)
dates = [start_date + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(days_in_training)]
actual = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(days_in_training)}, index=dates)

start_datetime = datetime(2016, 12, 1)
datetimes = [start_datetime + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(days_in_training)]
expected = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(days_in_training)}, index=datetimes)

assert(all(actual == expected))
```

Gives:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

Comment: try `assert(all(actual.values == expected.values))` here `.values` returns a np array so no index is involved

Comment: Well, yes. That was one of my suggestions, but it doesn't test if the dates also match. I could test that separately, but I was just wondering if there was an elegant solution to do everything at once.

Comment: why not just convert the index to date? `expected.index = expected.index.date`, then it will align

Comment: actually `actual == expected` just works already for me

Comment: What version pandas/numpy are you using? mine is 0.19.1 and 1.11.0

Comment: I had a bug in the original code, where the index of the second DataFrame wasn't a datetime. Please run again.
Pandas version: '0.18.1', Numpy version: '1.11.1'

Comment: still works for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference, through this blogpost (https://penandpants.com/2014/10/07/testing-with-numpy-and-pandas/) I found the function `pandas.util.testing.assert_frame_equal()` (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29de89c1d961bea7aa030422b56b061c09255b96/pandas/util/testing.py#L621)

This function has some flexibility in what it tests for. In addition it prints a summary why the DataFrames might not be considered equal, the line `assert(all(actual == expected))` only returns True or False, which makes debugging harder.